# HTTP to HTTPS is not working correct

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, mod-rewrite, https

I'm trying redirect my visitors to https with the code bellow in .httaccess.

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Everything works fine, when i type the URL in the address bar with www. or without. The problem is when i visiting the site from google. The redirect to https version is not working. Why is this happening,  make sense for me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Please try this in your htaccess file.

Comment: By google you meant google search website or google chrome browser?

Comment: Can you please provide a sample URL that is not working.